# How to get Windows version in Directory.Build.props for .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core-3.1

I use a global solution NuGet package that has issues with Windows 7 in the latest version. I now want to chose the older version of the NuGet package on Windows 7 until the issue gets fixed, but use the newer and much faster version on Windows 10.

I add the NuGet package reference in my Directory.Build.props but I can't find a way to add a property or condition to find the Windows version.

I tried using a parameter like

```xml
<OsVersion>
$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion@CurrentVersion)
</OsVersion>
```

but I can't read the registry from dotnet 3.1 build command. I tried [MSBuild]::GetRegistryValue and [MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView, but neither seems to work.

I found this bug in dotnet/sdk github which seems reading registry is not working for dotnet, https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/13958

So how do I get the Windows version so I can use it in the condition? Is there another way?

Thanks

My Directory.Build.Props

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OsVersion>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion@CurrentVersion)</OsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Choose>
        <When Condition="$(OsVersion) == '6.1'">
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="SomeNugetPackage">
                    <Version>1.7</Version>
                    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
                </PackageReference>
            </ItemGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
            <ItemGroup>
                <PackageReference Include="SomeNugetPackage">
                    <Version>1.10</Version>
                    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
                </PackageReference>
            </ItemGroup>
        </Otherwise>
    </Choose>
</Project>
```